# I can't show a toast inside a BroadcastReceiver unless first I created an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

In this code I try to show a toast two times inside a BroadcastReceiver. There is no problem with the first one, when previously I created an activity, but the second one the toast doesn't show. What is the problem? How can I show a toast without an activity? The problem could be that if just after showing a toast the application ends the toast does not show up?

```
    class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    val PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile"

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        if (intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) { //when unlock

            val settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
            var veces = settings.getInt("veces", 0)
            val limite = settings.getInt("limite", 3)
            veces++
            val editor = settings.edit()
            editor.putInt("veces", veces)

            editor.apply()
            if (veces % limite == 0) {   //
                val intent1 = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                context.startActivity(intent1)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Veces $veces", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()   //works
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Veces $veces", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()  //It doesn't work
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it is not the best solution but I have achieved what I wanted to do by creating a second transparent activity and I show the toast from within this transparent activity.I wonder if it is possible to show a toast from a BroadcasReceiver, without creating an activity.